# Form Paint event in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, onpaint

Weird issue:  I have application that I fire some code in the Form_Paint event for the main form, it works fine on my machine, but on other machines is not working at all.

I tried to debug the code on the other machine, and Form_Paint event is not triggered at all!

Comment: Check the **Handles** caluse with Form_Paint event.

Comment: With a description of any error messages or the steps to reproduce the problem it would be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

if it's working on your machine so it should work on others, try to put messagebox that show message and check if it fires on others machine or not, because maybe debug mode is not activated.

Comment: I did, and still not going through the Form_Paint event??

Answer (score 0):

the other machine may not have the .net framework installed. I ran into this problem when I made a great screen capture program and wanted to try it out on my laptop with windows xp installed.  Debug will not work but if you were to build the file and have the other machine install the .exe with the framework packaged with it then you'll be fine.

Comment: It appears that the code _is_ running on the other machine - "Form_Paint event is not triggered at all", so a missing framework can't be the problem...

Comment: I've had this happen twice and once it was definitely the lack of the .NET framework.  The other time I created a new vb project on my machine that was giving me problems and just copied the code over.  It took some time but in the end it worked on both machines.

Comment: Certainly, if the framework is missing, the code won't run, but if so, the OP would have seen the "this program requires the .NET framework to continue" message, or, on framework 1.x, the program would have crashed out with a 0x... error. No crash was mentioned in the question, however.